# Adding variable to user profile page in drupal 6

Tags: users

I have a custom module let say mymodule. One of the function in this module generates or returns  some contents. Forget about what the content is. My question is how could i add this content to user profile page. I tried to override using user-profile.tpl.php file. I could override the theme. But how to add a variable to this page that contains the required content so that i can echo the variable. Is there any preprocessing function that will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `hook_menu` in your custom module and use `MENU_LOCAL_TASK` as the type, and the path in your custom module needs to start with user/

```
function HOOK_menu() {
      $items['user/%user/yourpage'] = array(
        'title' => t('My Tab'),
        'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
        'page callback' => 'yourmodule_page', //your module page should be a function 
        //'page arguments'
      );
      return $items;
    }

function yourmodule_page()
{
   $uid = arg(1);
   $user = user_load($uid);
   //use user to get particular content belonging to them
   //return content
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the theme preprocess function [template_preprocess_user_profile](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.pages.inc/function/template_preprocess_user_profile/7) to provide your variables.